# MySQL using LIKE in query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to come up with a query that will generate results based on letter patterns of a string contained in the database.

Basically this is what I am trying to do:

```
Test 1: "T" => mysql returns: toys, tofu, telephones, turkeys, televisions, topaz
Test 2: "To" => mysql returns: toys, tofu, topaz
Test 3: "Toy" => mysql returns: toys
Test 4: "Toys" => mysql returns: toys
```

This is what i tried so far ($searchword corresponds to test case string):

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE prod_name LIKE %".$searchword."%");
```

Comment: Your term is a string and needs to be wrapped in single quotes. '%".$searchword."%' - additionally, % is a directional wildcard, so %T% would also match the word "match" since it has a T in it - plus, switch to PDO. mysql_ is deprecated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the quotes (`'%text%"`) to your query

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE prod_name LIKE '%".$searchword."%'");
```

@KaiQing comments that you could use this instead,and he's right if you just want the words that start with the '`searchword`':

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE prod_name LIKE '".$searchword."%'")
```

I.E:
if `searchword`=TOY, this query `WHERE prod_name LIKE '".$searchword."%'` will display TOYS,TOYZ,TOYXXX, etc but wont display XTOY, TITOY,ZTOY, etc.

If you want to find out more about how to use `like` take a look here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: I think he wants forward direction only. That would be '".$searchword."%' unless he wants %T% to match anything left and right of T.

Comment: Exactly - and in a more real world application, %T% would return "Toys" and "Hot Tub"